# Load data into materializecss slider dynamically using Angular ng-repeat not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, materialize

I can hover over the slider div and "copy image url" option is there thus data is setted correctly but slider is showing nothing, its just grey-blank.

If I remove the classes "slider,slides", then all of my data is popped up vertically but not when using "slider,slides" classes.

I have this in my main Html:

```
         $(document).ready(function () {
              $('.slider').slider();
             });
```

My Sample Json Data which I get through GET request in angular :

```
      cast: [
            {
                cast_id: 0,
                character: "Mark Watney",
                credit_id: "53e7e85e0e0a266f9a0029aa",
                id: 1892,
                name: "Matt Damon",
                order: 0,
                profile_path: "/eLAWpp5BLbTwjj35MbGzpL0QkWv.jpg"
            },
            {
                cast_id: 9,
                character: "Melissa Lewis",
                credit_id: "5466c78eeaeb8172820008e4",
                id: 83002,
                name: "Jessica Chastain",
                order: 1,
                profile_path: "/eyv98YlnRuOOUNCD1U6w2yZDRA2.jpg"
            },
            {
                cast_id: 11,
                character: "Annie Montrose",
                credit_id: "5497ab23c3a368054b0009b4",
                id: 41091,
                name: "Kristen Wiig",
                order: 2,
                profile_path: "/eqHjl70yPVAYcpYnqKk62a3pzDd.jpg"
            },
            {
                cast_id: 13,
                character: "Teddy Sanders",
                credit_id: "54a7fe92c3a3680c33001972",
                id: 8447,
                name: "Jeff Daniels",
                order: 3,
                profile_path: "/gai03gCu3DxMYxFympt7hUObpI5.jpg"
            }
          ]
```

Now i am setting this data from angular but the slider appears grey, I can confirm the image url by hovering over grey area and copying image url. But nothing is displayed in the div.

```
       <div class="row card-panel" ng-show="castShow">
                <div class="slider">
                    <ul class="slides">
                        <li ng-repeat="act in actors.cast">
                            <img ng-src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original{{act.profile_path}}">

                            <div class="caption" style="margin-top: 262px;margin-left:80px;">
                                <h5 class="indigo-text right-align" ng-bind="act.character"></h5>
                                <h6 class="white-text right-align" ng-bind="act.name"></h6>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

My angularJS code where I am getting and setting data:

```
      DetailsService.GetMovieCredits(mid).then(function (response) {
            var json = angular.fromJson(response);
            //var cast = json.cast;
            $scope.actors = json;
            $scope.castShow = true;
        }, function (response) {
        });
```

Comment: i not getting you question exactly. what do you mean by "I can hover over the slider and copy image url"

Comment: please clarify your question

Comment: my data is getting loaded(as I tested without slider and  slides class ) in ng-repeat actors but  nothing is getting displayed in the div.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a work around for the same. Why not we create a custom event and dispatch it when cast response has been fetched? And we can attach a listener on the same custom event and within the listener we can call `$('.slider').slider();`.

The angular code part will look something like this

```
DetailsService.GetMovieCredits(mid).then(function (response) {
        var json = angular.fromJson(response);
        $scope.actors = json;
        $scope.castShow = true;
        //Creating custom event for slider data loaded
        var event = document.createEvent('Event');
        event.initEvent('slider-ready',true,true);
        document.querySelector('.slider').dispatchEvent(event);
  }, function (response) {
    });
```

Then instead of calling 
`$(document).ready(function () {$('.slider').slider();});` from main.html
we have to do something like this

```
$('.slider).on('slider-ready', function (e) {
            //Adding timeout as direct function call was not working 
            setTimeout(function(){
                 $('.slider').slider();
            },1);      
});
```

It worked for me. Hopefully it helps. It is just a hack that I have come up with.